# Embedding Survey In Mobile Apps

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile

Don't know too much about the mobile space, so I hope I'm asking the right questions. Here goes...

Is it possible to embed a quick survey into mobile apps? These are custom surveys in HTML5 format. Not a commercial service like Wufoo. This is a proprietary system. The only thing the app developer would need is a JavaScript tag from me and the rest is handled by the script that’s called.

If you’ve played Temple Run 2 recently, you might notice that sometimes before your run starts, the screen goes black, and an ad pops up. If you close out of the ad, you go back to the game. My survey would behave the same way. Each time the user answers a question and moves on to the next, a call to my server is made where the data will be captured and recorded.

Is something like this possible at the scripting level, or would the developer need to implement such a feature at the Java or Objective C level? Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

That is totally possible on Android, you would just load a popup on android with a WebView (a browser like component) that loads a fixed page. 
The loaded page is totally under your control and can be changed from the outside without changing a line of Java code.

Comment: But the webView itself needs to be invoked though Java right? So I would need the app developer to edit Java code in order to load the WebView that contains my survey?

Comment: yes he would have to do the logic of displaying the WebView the first time, but from then on you would have control of its contents from the outside

Comment: Yea, that's not what we're looking for. Ideally this would be as simple as a javascript tag that is dropped into the app source code. The same way you would display Google Ads on your blog by way of example.