# Android Mobile App Survey

Tags: android, webview, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a survey on my website that I'd like to deliver to my Android app users (like demographics and such). I'm wondering what the best way to do this is - do you think that using a WebView to just display the survey webpage would work since they'd need to have internet to get the survey questions anyway? Or is it a better idea to pass the survey questions to the app, create a native view and then send the results back to my Rails server?

From this thread it sounds like it's pretty easy to do one question - [Embedding Survey In Mobile Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308138/embedding-survey-in-mobile-apps)

But my survey is around 10 questions, so mainly I'm wondering about app performance/feel. Especially in poor internet connection scenarios.

Comment: It is better idea to pas the survey question to the qpp and create a native view and then send result back to your rails server

Comment: Ok, I figured :). Just thought I'd check. Thanks!

Comment: It depends. Is this something that may change periodically? Do you need to keep the user in-app or can you farm the survey out to a third party browser? If the answer is yes to either I'd consider sticking to an html form and save your self the headache of writing the native UI.